# Convergence to a uniformly distributed r.v.

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence

For $n \geq 1$, let $X_{n}$ have the uniform distribution on the interval $(\alpha_{n},2+\alpha_{n})$, where $\alpha_{n}=(-1)^{n}$. The sequence $(X_{n})$ is said to be $\mathbf{stochastic}$ $\mathbf{bounded}$,or $\mathbf{tight}$, if its sequence of distribution measures $\mu_{n}$ is tight. This is equivalent to saying that $\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\exists$ a constant $k=k_{\epsilon}$ such that $\sup_{n\geq 1}P(|x_{n}>k)<\epsilon$. (*)

The part I need help with is the following:
"Show that $X_{2k}$ converges in distribution to a uniform (on what interval ?)"

Now, from the way the problem was worded, I assume that $X_{2k}$ is also uniform, just on the interval $(\alpha_{2k},2+\alpha_{2k}) = ((-1)^{2k},2+(-1)^{2k})=(1,3)$.

This problem has multiple parts, and this is part (B). Part (A) asked us to show that $(X_{n})_{n\geq 1}$ is tight. I know there is a result that says that if $(X_{n})_{n\geq1}$ is tight (actually, its probability measure is tight, but then there's another result (Helly's Selection Principle) that says that the fact that the probability measure is tight implies that the sequence of r.v.'s is tight), then it must have a convergent subsequence. This, however, does not imply that $(X_{2k})$ is necessarily that subsequence (although I wonder if something could be done with the inequality (*) above?) or that it necessarily converges to a uniform.

Then, there's the possibility of using the density functions. If I can prove that $(X_{2k})$'s density function converges to a uniform density function, I will have solved the problem. Only thing is, the fact that $k$ here is given to be a constant is confusing me. Is it a constant sequence?

Please, if you can at least point me in the right direction, I would be eternally grateful!

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: What is the distribution of $X_{2k}$?

Comment: I edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is much easier than what you're looking for!

By hypothesis, $X_{2k}$ has uniform distribution on $(1,3)$ for all $k$. So, the sequence of distributions of $X_{2k}$ is constant, hence trivially convergent with limit the uniform distribution on $(1,3)$.

Comment: +1. One might add somewhere the words "hence trivially tight".